# How to pass (optional) completion handler closure to transitionFromViewController in Swift?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, swift

In a ViewController in my app I call transitionFromViewController but always get the following error when passing in a closure to the completion: argument.

```
Type '() -> Void' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
```

Here's the function call:

```
    self.transitionFromViewController(
        self.currentVC,
        toViewController: newController,
        duration: 0.2,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
        nil,
        completion: { finished in
            fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            toViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(containerViewController)
            toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds
    })
```

According to code completion the method signature is as follows:

```
transitionFromViewController(fromViewController: UIViewController, toViewController: UIViewController, duration: NSTimeInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: () -> Void(), completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot pass nil to `animations` paramere `() -> Void()` declared as not `optional`

Pass empty `closure` if you want

```
self.transitionFromViewController(
        self.currentVC,
        toViewController: newController,
        duration: 0.2,
        options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionCrossDissolve,
        animations: { () -> Void in

        },
        completion: { finished in
            fromViewController.removeFromParentViewController()
            toViewController.didMoveToParentViewController(containerViewController)
            toViewController.view.frame = containerViewController.view.bounds
    })
```

Comment: before remove you should call willMoveToParentViewController(nil) according to the documentation!

Answer (score 2):

I think following code should help you :

```
self.transitionFromViewController(fromViewController, toViewController: toViewController, duration: 0.1, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
            // code for animations
            }) { (value: Bool) -> Void in
            // code after completion
        }
```

Where, // code for animations - code you want to execute during the block.
And,  // code after completion - code you want to execute after the completion of the block.